# cannot reshape array of size x into shape y error during np.load (python)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am working on a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) based on an example given in class. First time trying this.

The data (x_train.npy, x_test.npy, y_test.npy, y_train.npy) was given to us

I loaded the data as follows:

```
import numpy as np

x_test = np.load('x_test.npy')
x_train = np.load('x_train.npy')
y_test = np.load('y_test.npy')
y_train =  np.load('y_train.npy')
```

But the code fails x_test and x_train with cannot reshape array of size # into shape #
ie. for x_train I get the following error:

```
cannot reshape array of size 31195104 into shape (300,224,224,3)
```

I understand that 300 * 224 * 224 * 3 is not equal to 31195104 and that is why it's complaining. However, I don't understand why it's trying to reshape during load.

Is the load method wrong, or is it the file? Should I be reshaping this data after loading? If I should be reshaping the data, how do I figure out what the reshaping numbers should be?

Comment: Most likely the file has been damaged/truncated  Given those dimensions I'd expect something like 360Mb.

Comment: @hpaulj talked with the professor, and he says the data is not the problem, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: If all you are doing calling `np.load` on a valid `npy` file, you aren't doing anything wrong.  Did you download the files from somewhere?  Try reloading them.  To confirm my suspicions, what the size of the problem file?

Comment: @hpaulj I figure it out. It was that the file I downloaded did not download correctly the first time, and redownloading it helped. Thank you for the help!!